# REST API call via Postman to read Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder

I am new to API call. I'm attempting to retrieve a journey together with its data from SFMC.

- Should i use POST or GET request?
- What URL goes to the request?
- For header, i have specified the Authorization as "Bearer Access Token", and the Content Type as application/json. What else i'm i missing?
- What code should i enter into the Body section.

Comment: Most of the questions in this post are not related to SF, but rather basic programing. I would strongly suggest you do some research on each of the items you have in the post. after that, if you run into any specific SF related issues while implementing,  feel free to open a new post =) .

Comment: @glls umm... these questions are absolutely related to - and specific to - SF and the unique SFMC API.

Comment: imo, these look like basic REST api questions that just happen to have 'marketing cloud' in context

Comment: @glls Like i mentioned in my first statement, i am new to API calls - so what i may ask maybe basic to a well experienced folks. Please bear with me. Thank you.

Comment: @glls these are not basic or generic REST api questions... these questions are specific to retrieving a specific journey via the SFMC API.

Comment: I guess we will leave this at every developer has their own definition of basic ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @glls If you can also leave your input based on the feedback so far - that would be really helpful. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, but i'll pass, your question has too many questions. if you narrow down your issue to a specific problem in relation to how you are calling the api, it would be relevant and on topic, but as is, i'm voting to close. Please take a moment to read [ask]. please make sure to go through the documentation and whn you open a question, include what you have tried, where you are stuck and any relevant error messages. This way, it will be easier to assist. Thanks =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good news... this is well documented. Your questions (e.g. POST or GET, which URL, how to authenticate, etc.) are all covered [**here**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getInteractionById.htm).

Specific answers to your questions:

- `GET`
- `/interaction/v1/interactions/{id}`
- For headers: pass 1) `"Content-Type": "application/json"` and then 2) `"Authorization: Bearer <YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>"`
- No body is needed for this

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've leveraged the document you shared before. So far, i've used the GET request together with the /interaction/v1/interactions/{id}. I'm having a hard time locating the ID/External Key for Journey. I'm getting a 404 error. Also, should be specifying the version number of the journey in the GET request URL? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Any idea on this @krigi?